# Some Swift 4 Codes Does not Executed in different iPhone version

Tags: ios10, ios11, swift4

So, I have some codes that have to run in quite range iPhone version, from 5s to 8 and 8+, with minimum iOS version is iOS 10. These codes suppose to show some menu items based on the user loggin status. If there was a user login, it suppose to show the menu like this:

[if there was a user logged in](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UdZXExp70cB35EdMNxu5nJKyeya8bniZ)

if not, it suppose to show the menu like this:

[if there was not a user logged in](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kq8lrMs8R6wMLy0qYHLuSctSz8lf6z4F)

Here is the code:

```
    if let LoginStatus = userdefault.value(forKey: "loginStatus") as? Bool {
            if LoginStatus { //if there is a user login, do these things
                iconMenu = ["icoFeatured", "icoOrder", "icoReward", "icoPayment", "icoReferral", "icoSupport", "icoSettings"]
                titleMenu = ["Featured", "Order History", "Reward Cards", "Payment Methods", "Referral Code", "Support", "Settings"]
                titleMenu2 = ["About", "Logout"]
            } else { //if there is NO user login, do these things
                iconMenu = ["icoFeatured", "icoSupport", "icoSettings", "icoClose"]
                titleMenu = ["Featured", "Support", "Settings", "Crash Test"]
                titleMenu2[titleMenu2.count-1] = "Login/Register"
            }
        }
```

Everything is okay when I test it using 6/6+, 6s/6s+, 7/7+ and 8/8+, but when I test it using 5s, it is not executed my optional binding

```
 if let LoginStatus = userdefault.value(forKey: "loginStatus") as? Bool {...}
```

I'm wondering, how can it happen? iPhone 5s should be able to execute Swift 4 codes correctly when iOS10 and later is installed, should not it? If anyone can help me figure out about this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The iPhone 5s is pretty much the earliest model that supports iOS 11 so iOS 10 shouldn't be an issue.  Are you absolutely sure nothing else is different between the test environments.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I’m 100% sure that the only different is the iphone model, I finally updated the iphone 5s to iOS11 to see whether the issue is persist or not, and sadly it is.